# When should I use the tag for the OS version?

Tags: discussion, tags

On Stack Overflow, a version tag (e.g. "c#-4.0") is used when the question is about a feature specific for that version.
Is the same true for the OS tags used on *Ask Different*, or should I use the OS tags only to report the OS I am using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our version-specific OS tags use the 'big cat' name of the OS release.

```
10.4 -> tiger  
10.5 -> leopard  
10.6 -> snow-leopard  
10.7 -> lion
```

**Use one of these when you have a question that's OS-specific.

When your question is not OS-specific, use the generic `osx` tag.**

**Tags should not be used just to tell us what version of the OS you're using; add that to the question itself.**

Examples:

*"How can I rename Desktops in Lion?"*
Desktops (Spaces) changed a lot in Lion; this is a very Lion-specific question.
[lion]

*"Error when connecting to my Mac with SSH"*
This is a general troubleshooting question. While it may be useful to know the OS, it isn't a question specifically about that OS.
[osx], version info in the question.

Comment: I was referring to those. The question is when they should be used: Should I use them when I ask something that is specific for an OS version, or just to report I am using a specific OS version?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Updated.